# Trying to use style.height to expand div box incrementaly

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone understand why the div id "block" isn't expanding as it's values increment upward? here's the script code. help greatly appreciated! Here's my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fh2q0cgp/

```
var i = 0; 


var anim = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 200);

function myTimer(){
    i++; 
      document.getElementById("block").style.width = i; 
      document.getElementById("block").style.height = i;  
 // alert(i);
    document.getElementById("information").innerHTML = i; 


  if(i===100){

  clearInterval(anim); 
}
};
```

Comment: Can you use CSS3 transformations instead JS ?

Comment: I think i can yeah, but wanna do some java-script manipulation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add + "px" in front of variable i.

Comment: you hit the nail on the head niceone! seems to work now.